# Error when user tries to send next message immediately in Realm

Tags: ios, swift3, realm, realm-list

Here are my two **realm models** used to create objects in realm database.

```
class Users: Object {
    dynamic var phoneNumber:String = ""
    dynamic var messageSenderName:String = ""
    let userMessages = List<Messages>()

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "phoneNumber"
    }
    // convenience init() here
}

class Messages: Object{
    dynamic var id = UUID().uuidString
    dynamic var phoneNumber:String = ""
    dynamic var messageSenderName:String = ""
    dynamic var messageBody:String = ""
    dynamic var message_id:String = ""
    dynamic var messageTime:String = ""

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "id"
    }
    // convenience init here
}
```

This my RosterViewController where I show the 'phoneNumber' and latest 'messageBody' in tableViewCell. I am using **XMPP Framework** to receive messages and **SwiftyXMLParser** to parse the xml messages.

```
class RosterViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{
    var realm : Realm!
    dynamic var users = Users()
    var userResult : Results<Users>!
    dynamic var messagedata = Messages()
    var messageResult : Results<Messages>!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        realm = try! Realm()
        notificationToken = realm.observe{ notification, realm in
            self.contactsTableView.reloadData()
        }
    }

    func xmppStream(_ sender: XMPPStream, didReceive message: XMPPMessage) {
         .......
        // parse xml and set object values here     

        userResult = realm.objects(Users.self)
        messageResult = realm.objects(Messages.self)

        try! realm.write {
            users.userMessages.append(messagedata)
            realm.add(users, update: true)
            realm.add(messagedata, update: true)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to append the messages dynamically to the **users** List of the respective message sender. I am not able to do so. I am receiving messages in real time so they should get appended to the list and thus reflect the same on tableView.
First message is shown properly, but when same user sends another message immediately then I get an error saying:

**RLMException', reason: 'Attempting to modify object outside of a write transaction - call beginWriteTransaction on an RLMRealm instance first**

I have also tried a lot, but could not get any fixes or workaround. Please help me solve this issue, just began with realm. Thank you!

Comment: There are some issues with this code in general but are you saying that when the app receives a message, your want to append it to the user that *sent* the message i.e. the *respective message sender*?

Comment: @Jay. Yes I want to append it to that _respective message sender_. But whenever I send second message immediately (same user or other), I get the above error. Can you please tell what's wrong. Thank you.